# Flutter localstorage.getItem() returns null

Tags: flutter, local-storage

I'm using a Flutter package called `localstorage` to save the token and the user id I got from an API backend. I'm successfully saving the data as I'm seeing from Chrome's local storage:

```
class AuthService {
  final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('my_app_session');
  ....

  login(context, email, password) async {
      ...
      storage.setItem('id', res['data']['id'].toString());
      storage.setItem('token', res['token']['access_token']);
      ...
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/somepage');
  });
}
```

[image]

Then from a ChangeNotifier model:

```
class OrganizationModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  ...

  var orgService = new OrganizationService();
  ...

  Future fetch() async {
    List res = await orgService.fetch();
    ...
  }
}
```

Lastly, on `OrganizationService`:

```
class OrganizationService {
  final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('my_app_session');

  _token() {
    var token = storage.getItem('token');
    print(token);
    return token;
  }
}
```

The problem is `token` always returns `null`. I tried another new entry via setItem() just to test it and it completely replaced the entire localstorage with the new entry as if it doesn;t see the existing ones.

Any ideas why is this happening based on my workflow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var ready = await storage.ready; 
print('searching ${key} is $ready'); 
dynamic userJson = storage.getItem(key);
```

Just check storage.ready and search item, that's it.

Answer (score 3):

To allow data to be persisted,

Please remember to check for storage.ready even for data uploading, setItem().

**Uploading data:**

```
await storage.ready;
await storage.setItem('name', 'Abolfazl');
```

**Retrieving data:**

```
await storage.ready;
final name = await storage.getItem('name');
```

Answer (score 0):

Migrate away from localstorage because it is not encrypted and the data persist on your local machine.  Instead use FlutterSecureStorage for state restoration.

```
I use flutter_secure_storage: ^9.0.0 for local storage because it is encrypted.

 final storage = const FlutterSecureStorage();

 extractFromStorage().then((value) {});

Future<bool> extractFromStorage() async {
 try {
 String _local_employeeEmail = await storage.read(key: "email") ?? "";
 setState(() {
 _employeeEmail = _local_employeeEmail;
 });
 return true;
 } catch (e) {
 DialogCaller.showErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
 }
 return false;
 }

Future<void> setStorage(MasterMonitor model) async {
 try {
 await storage.write(
 key: "email",
 value: model.data.email,
 );
 } catch (e) {
 DialogCaller.showErrorDialog(context, e.toString());
 }
 }
```